# Convert DateTime to UTC date time

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime-format

As per my client requirement,I need to send current datetime in UTC format(below format).

```
FORMAT: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MsMsMsZ     'Ms is milliseconds
EXAMPLE: 2014-02-28T15:59:23.000Z       'Z is Time Zone Designator(TZD) and it must be Z
```

When I try to convert datetime in VB.Net I am getting the following format which is not 
equivilant to above format. 
Milliseconds should be only 3 digits and should show Z at the end.

Here is my code.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("o"))
2019-03-13T16:47:55.9620000-06:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the current, local time to UTC (Zulu) with [DateTime.UtcNow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow?view=netframework-4.7.2). Afterwards, you can get your [Custom Date and Time Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2) from it with code like this:

```
Dim currentTimeUTC As DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow
Dim strCurrentTimeUTC As String = currentTimeUTC.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
Debug.Print(strCurrentTimeUTC)
```

Output on my system was displayed as:

```
2019-03-13T20:55:28.493Z
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the "kind" of datetime you are using.
Eg. the following code:

```
Dim dt As New DateTime(2019, 1, 1, 3, 4, 23, DateTimeKind.Utc)
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("o"))
```

will produce: 2019-01-01T03:04:23.0000000Z

See: [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) with special attention the the "O" "o" standard string and the `The Round-trip ("O", "o")` Format Specifier.`

Comment: This would give you six decimals for the milliseconds, though, instead of the three digits that they want...